# Best method for modulating a voltage by 50mV

Tags: circuit-design

Some context - building a flight simulator that replicates a WWII aircraft.  I have a dual ammeter/voltmeter that displays amps by using a shunt resistor that generates a 50mV drop from the reference voltage (28V) at 150 amps and the reference voltage when a button is pressed.  My challenge is I would like to drive this same instrument from an Arduino.

Both the reference voltage and the amp signal voltage need to be modulated (reference from 0-28V, and amp from ref-50mV - ref).  My plan was to have separate PWM outputs from the Arduinos drive "something" that could generate the appropriate voltages to drive the instrument.  Identifying that "something" is my challenge.  I'm also aware that I may need some kind of feedback/controller to manage the amp signal.

What I need is PWM controllable variable resistor.  I don't think that exists (at least Google doesn't lead me anywhere).  I think if I can find the component I need I can design the appropriate circuit around it.

Comment: Be aware questions that ask for the "best" something are likely to be closed. Consider rephrasing your question, and including a question mark in the body of the question.

Comment: What is the correlation between V and I sense voltages that you want to create?  Voltages are easy to modulate, but more details are needed. Especially the presence of switched inductive EMI nearby.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it's a pretty clean EMI environment.  I have a software model of the electrical system of the aircraft that outputs current bus voltage and current.  The simulated bus voltage will vary from about 20-28V depending on simulated load and the simulated current will vary from 0-150A.  So for the BUS, or reference voltage going to the gauge, I need a 0-5V signal to translate to a 20-28V output, This output also serves as the reference for the ammeter signal, so the second 0-5V signal should vary the voltage on the a separate terminal from BUS minus 50mv to BUS.

Comment: As I understand, you need an OpAmp amplifier with gain of 1.6 and DC offset of 20V at output. From this output you go trough a resistor into a variable current sink, which controls the 50mV drop across this resistor. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an approach:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKLk5t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How it works:

1. R1 and C2 form a low pass filter to get analog DC 0-5V
2. R1 and R2 form a voltage divider to offset DC range to 8.7-12.24V
3. R3 and R4 set OpAmp gain to 2.3 to configure 8V delta-U at output
4. Offset and gain define a voltage range of 20-28V at OUT_1
5. PWM2 feeds Q1 and forms with R8 a switched current sink of 1mA
6. R7, C1 and R6 form a low pass filter for the current sink output
7. R5 is the shunt resistor to tansform 1mA to -50mV relative to OUT_1
8. D1 is a protection against small current coming from +30 if PWM is not configured as output (MCU reset)

If you need bidirectional 50mV difference, this will need much more components. The function depends on 30V supply, deviations affect precision. R2 and R8 are calculated for "ideal" MCU outputs and may need a little adjustment. The values of the capacitors are only a guess for typical PWM frequencies.

Comment: Thank you!  I will put together a prototype and try it out.

Comment: OpAmp TLE2021 has minor advantages here, better RI and some volts more headroom at VCC but for a prototype good old LM324 will do

Comment: just wanted to let you know that it worked pretty much as designed!  I learned quite a bit, too, so thank you!  A little bit of tweaking of resistor values will be required to dial it in, but it's pretty cool to watch it work!  Video of your circuit in action...https://youtu.be/2cFyzEKsreI

Comment: @JoeEnzminger Thank you for your feedback! Nice video

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is available with the Arduino, but if you can remove and replace the shunt resistor, every time you increase the shunt resistance by 10 you decrease the current measured by 10.  To get 150mA to respond like 150A you need a shunt 1000 times higher in resistance.

Comment: I'm not actually measuring current.  I'm simulating the measurement of current.  The gauge measures current by measuring the voltage drop across a shunt.  To simulate that, I need to recreate that voltage drop in proportion to the indication I want to see on the gauge.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar while designing flight simulators, not WW2 but later ones such as C130 and KC135. The indicators or even complete cockpit might have been taken from scrapped aircraft.

You need to find out what the actual current is required to drive the meter: it may only be some tens of milliamps.

You can then do pretty much what you are planning. You can create a PWM DAC followed by an amplifier to create the current required by the indicator.

Be aware that you may need to generate both positive and negative voltages as the original use might measure both charge and discharge currents.